# Interceptor issue with Java EE7

Tags: glassfish, cdi, interceptor, java-ee-7

I'm testing / switching to Java EE7 (Glassfish 4) and one of the issues I have is with Interceptors, whenever I try to run the project I am getting the following error.

> SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment
>   failure:WELD-001417 Enabled interceptor class
>   com.xxxxxx.security.SecuredInterceptor in
>   file:/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/target/xxxxxx/WEB-INF/beans.xml@7 is neither
>   annotated @Interceptor nor registered through a portable extension

I'm looking at section 1.3.6 of the CDI 1.1 specification it doesn't look like anything has changed, so what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using;

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Secured {}
```

```
@Secured
@Interceptor
public class SecuredInterceptor implements Serializable
{
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object interceptSecured(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
    <interceptors>
        <class>com.xxxxxx.security.SecuredInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Comment: Where is your interceptor packed? in the war file?  There were actually a lot of interceptor changes in EE7.

Comment: John is correct. The rules governing interceptors aren't specified by CDI, they're in the Interceptor sub spec from EJBs.

Comment: I'm only using a WAR file for the project, its a basic Netbeans > Maven > Web Application project that I've just started to test EE7 with.

Answer (score 5):

From section 12.1 of the CDI spec.

> A bean archive which contains a beans.xml file with no version has a default bean discovery mode of all.

Your version 1.1 beans.xml has `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`. Change beans.xml to `bean-discovery-mode="all"` and my guess is it will work just like it does when you remove the version from beans.xml and use the old namespace, as in a CDI 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be Glassfish bug related to 1.1 version of beans.xml

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20667